# How to make nested for loops faster in python or an alternative more efficient method?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

First, I apologize in advance for the formatting of the below, for the life of me I can't figure out how to get this form to accept my code, it keeps pushing an error that I appear to have not formatted some of my code correctly but I cannot find the formatting mistake.

For this problem, I have two Data sets that I need to iterate through,

Data Set One contains two columns, column one is a unique identification number (ID). Column two is holds a data frame for each identification number.

Each ID Data Fame contains a Date Column and a Status column that is set to 1 as default  (representing false)

Data Set Two contains columns for ID and a Start and End date.

The end results is to iterate through the unique IDs pull its data frame and check, for each date listed if their is a corresponding event with matching ID in data set two. If there is it then checks to see if the current date is between the start and end dates and if so changes the 1 to a 0 (representing True)

What I what need returned is data set one with each unique ID"s data frame set to show which dates had events occurring for that ID.

DATA SET ONE example, nomenclature not perfectly accurate to code below

> | INDEX | ID | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 1 | [date column, status column] |
> | 1 | 2 | [date column, status column] |
> | 2 | 3 | [date column, status column] |

DATA SET TWO example, nomenclature not perfectly accurate to code below

> | INDEX | ID | Begin Date | End Date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 1 | Date | Date |
> | 1 | 2 | Date | Date |
> | 2 | 3 | Date | Date |
> | 3 | 2 | Date | Date |
> | 4 | 4 | Date | Date |
> | 5 | 1 | Date | Date |

I can get the below code to work and it returns what I am looking for, the problem is scaling. I have over 20,000 id's, 180,000 individual events and need to check five years worth of dates to determine each day if that ID had an event.

What I am currently using is nested Loops and a few functions that I defined to do the logical checks. It works if I feed just a few lines but when I try to run the full data set it takes hours (I've let it run for 12 plus before manually stopping, I've never been able to get it to run to completion)

I've read into using where() or mask() and have tried using apply() with the data frame but cannot figure out how to pass the correct indices to get the desired results.

I've also read into vectorization but am still too new and inexperienced with python to understand how to apply to this problem. Both should be viable and orders of magnitude faster than using the python for loop though.

Am I missing something, is there an easy way to iterate through data frames without requiring the long processing times required by for loops.

```
    def check_ID(id, id_event):
    
      cs = pd.DataFrame(date_status.loc[ id:id,].drop(columns=['status']))

      event_id = pd.DataFrame(event_data.loc[ id_event:id_event,].drop(columns=['Begin Date','End Date','Consecutive_Days']))
    
      if  cs.equals(event_id):
        return(True)
      else:
        return(False)
```

```
    def is_event_true(id_index, id_event_index, date_index):

      if (date_status.loc[id_index,'status'].loc[date_index,'Date'] >= event_data.loc[id_event_index,'Begin Date'] and date_status.loc[id_index,'status'].loc[date_index,'Date'] < event_data.loc[id_event_index,'End Date']):

        return(True)

      else:  
        return(False)
```

```
    for i in date_status.index:

      for x in event_data.index:

        if check_ID(i,x):

          for y in date_status.loc[i,'status'].index:

            if is_event_true(i,x,y):

              date_status.loc[i,'status'].loc[y,'Status'] = 0
```

Comment: please provide *example inputs*. Markdown tables aren't really helpful, give us *code* to create an example. Likewise with the *outputs*.

Comment: If it is true that each ID in `DATA SET ONE` is unique, then the first thing I would do is iterate over `DATA SET ONE` to create a Python dictionary with each row's ID value as a key and the row's other data as the corresponding value.  Then you can use that Python dictionary to look up the data associated with any given ID very quickly (i.e. close to `O(1)` time instead of `O(N)` time), which ought to reduce the complexity of your subsequent code from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)` and thereby give you a significant speedup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed in iterating through dataframes you need parallelization.

Some options for parallelization:

1.joblib

2.concurrent.futures

3.dask - for bigger data